# Range Date Picker using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm new to programming world, been working on creating a responsive Dashboard. I'm looking for a range datepicker using angular 2. I have searched a lot on web but couldn't get anything helpful. I need help to include range datepicker module in my code. 
Suggestions are most welcomed. It will only help me to grow in this field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this there you will found verity of datepciker

- [www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

see `Restrict` calendar as per your need

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, will try and post the response.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 date range picker

[GitHub](https://github.com/kekeh/mydaterangepicker)

[Online demo](https://kekeh.github.io/mydaterangepicker/)